# reveal editor when debug with breakpoint step

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

is possible to auto-reveal a window when track step in debug mode ?
When i do next step and the instance is in other sheet, the window no open automatically.

`"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,`
will work fine for ctrl click reference, but seem not affect the debug mode with breakPoint tracking.

So the issue is when i push next step, if the step is in other files, i need search the file and open manually.

I made a little sketch to show the behavior i want.
sorry for my poor english guys.
[image]

EDIT ADD GIF OF THE BEHAVIOR
[image]
thanks for help

Comment: It works for me.  Do you have a `skipFiles` option set in your launch command?  If so, remove or modify it.  You could also just click on the function entered into at the top of the call stack in the debug panel.  If yours isn't there, try to unhide by rightclicking on any debug panel header like `Variables` and click the `Call Stack` (or language equivalent) to show it.

Comment: no `skipFiles` in debug, yes it work if a double click on a `call stack` but i want this auto.

Comment: It is automatic for me so I am not sure why it isn't for you.  I see you have the relevant editor opened in a different but minimized row - the file gets highlighted just not maximized.  If the file is not already opened in a different row/editor group does it work for you to open automatically?

Comment: So I don't believe vscode will maximize the editor group "which is stepped into".  It works if the file is in the same editor group but not across editor groups.  You may need to open an issue on this if you don't get a good answer.  A workaround is to first `join` all your editor groups into one - but it can't be reversed I don't think.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to express.
`the file gets highlighted just not maximized` , i need click on manually to maximize, and it just strange we don't have option to force `maximized` when the debugger step into a file inside a `editor groups`.

I wanted to know especially if there were options in `settings.json` to allow this behavior.

Comment: i add a animated gif of the behavior.
you can see when i push next step , the file highlighted but no maximize.

Comment: i add issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed thanks ............................

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79633#issuecomment-528049293